# Use T4 template as a dll

Tags: .net, templates, dll, t4

Is there any way to create dll from T4 templates and generate codes from this dll? At now I need to set parameters by hard coded and when you save (Press Ctrl + S), the template start to generate, but there must be a good reusable way. does any one have any suggestion?

**Update**

I need a Library Application Include T4 Templates and I can pass parameters from any app that referenced to this library and get generated code as a return. but i don't know how can I create a dll from T4

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You mention a shortcut, but don't mention the application your using, suggestions to do what exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is Runtime (also called Preprocessed) templates.
With these you'll generate the template code rather than the template output.  You can then embed that code in any part of your app with no runtime dependencies on T4.

MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx

Oleg Sych's blog on the subject: http://www.olegsych.com/2009/09/t4-preprocessed-text-templates

Comment: I ask a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988124/call-methods-in-transformtext-method-at-t4-preprocessed-template would you please check it?