# Call Methods in Transformtext() Method at T4 Preprocessed Template

Tags: .net, templates, t4

I use T4 and Preprocessed Template to generate some codes. So When I add all of the templates directly in .tt file every things is OK like the following:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<html><body>
<h1>Sales for Previous Month</h2>
<table>
    <# for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
       { #>
         <tr><td>Test name <#= i #> </td>
             <td>Test value <#= i * i #> </td> </tr>
    <# } #>
 </table>
This report is Company Confidential.
</body></html>
```

But I need to grouped codes in some methods and call methods in `transformText()` Method:

MyTemplate.tt file is like the following:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#+ 

    private string header(){
#>
<html><body>
<h1>Sales for Previous Month</h2>

<#+ 
    return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();
}


private string body() {
#>
    <table>
    <#+ for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { #>

     <tr><td>Test name <#= i #> </td>
         <td>Test value <#= i * i #> </td> </tr>
    <#+ } #>
 </table>
<#+ 
    return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();
}


private string footer(){
#>
    This report is Company Confidential ..
</body></html>
<#+ 
    return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();
}
#>
```

And related MyTemplate.cs file is like the following:

```
// .... 

public virtual string TransformText()
    {
        return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();
    }
// ....
```

So I call the methods in `TransformText()` method like this:

```
// .... 

 public virtual string TransformText()
    {
        header();
        body();
        footer();
        return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();
    }
// ....
```

So every thing is OK yet, but if I change any thing in .tt file and Save it, the .cs file regenerated again and `TransformText()` Method return to first implementation (without any calling)?

So how can I use some methods and generate codes in Preprocessed Template? What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#
    header ();
    body ();
    foooter ();
#>
<#+ ... the rest ... #>
```

PS. Not sure why you call inside header, body and footer

```
return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();
```

Comment: Also note, you'd general make the submethods void rather than returning the current progress of the GenerationEnvironment method.

Comment: @FuleSnabel I ask a similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838142/put-all-methods-in-one-tt-file-and-use-it-in-another-t4-files-in-codetemplates would you please check it